# Oracle Apex radio group

Tags: oracle-apex, radio-group

Environment: Oracle DB 11gR2.
Framework: Oracle Apex 5.1

I have a table with Column Product_id,Monthly_rate and Yearly_rate

When user will select Option for- Monthly

Then I want to pass below three values in another pages according to selection

1. Product_id
2. Monthly -- User select this option
3. Monthly_rate

Similarly for Yearly selection I want to pass

1. Product_id
2. Yearly  -- user select this option
3. Yearly_rate.

I want to use radio group How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, this is my first post in stack overflow. I also need to know the answer by the way. :)

Comment: I would suggest using google for "oracle apex radio group" to start, then look at the docs. There are *lots* of example of how to do this on the web. Then, if you have tried suggested solutions and the docs and things don't works as they should, then come here, and post your question. You should include what you tried that did not work and what version you are on.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a Radio Group in Apex the selected value will be stored as the Item Value on Submit. As with every other Item in Apex you can then reference that Item Value from all other Pages with this Syntax:

```
:P1_MY_RADIO_GROUP
```

Where **1** is the Page ID and **MY_RADIO_GROUP** the Item Name.

When you want to maintain that selection in another Radio Group just use the Item Value as the Source for those Radio Groups.